# Looking to create a video streaming app in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

Iam looking to create a video streaming app in django. The app doesnt involve user uploads, only streaming. I upload the video, and the user views it, more like netflix, but for 5 to 10 secs videos. Please help me with the basics and the requirements. I know how django works but iam totally new with the videos part. Please help me.

Comment: This is something you shouldn’t ask in this web site. Here is your problems. You can google it or look for it in youtube

Answer (score 2):

You will probably want to use cloud storage like Amazon S3 to host your videos, and read into existing django video libraries and projects.

https://github.com/andrewebdev/django-video

This is a good starting point, but beware that a large scale video streaming platform is not a trivial task - especially for a beginner.

Comment: I could not figure how it works. But I found some interesting stuff in it. BTW I hope you can add more examples which are vividly to read and learn for novice.